# Why is the probability of pulling two oranges out of a basket without replacement not zero or one but rather $\frac{6}{11}$?

Tags: probability

> In a basket, there are a certain number of oranges and 3 apples. The probability of pulling two oranges out without replacement is $\frac{6}{11}$. What is the total number of pieces of fruit in the basket before any are removed?

A person either pulls two oranges out or they do not. Why is picking two oranges a random-event?

Comment: You either win the lottery or you do  not, Thus, playing the lottery is not a random event at all.

Comment: @Glen_b Perhaps you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re overthinking it. Let n be the number of oranges. Then there are n+3 pieces of fruit in the basket. So the probability of pulling out the first orange is n/(n+3). After that there are n-1 oranges left in the basket. You can take it from there.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Unlike a lot of questions that get posted here, this one seems to be philosophical: what is random once I reach into the bucket and pull out fruit, rather than how to do the calculation. Therefore, I’m not sure this answers the asked question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question follows a probability problem description. The problem writer's implicit assumption could have been made explicit by adding another sentence after the first: "Assume individual fruit selections are random and independent".

Without this assumption or something similar, there need be no randomness involved, since the person could simply look in the basket before choosing, or select by feel. So you are right in questioning whether picking oranges needs to be a random event

Answer (score 1):

Hi: Without replacement means that it's the product of the probabilities on each  dependent draw. So, let B = number of bananas.

Probability of banana on first draw = b/b+3 = P1

Probability of banana on second draw = (b-1)/((b-1)+3) = P2.

So, P1 $\times$ P2 = 6/11 and solve for b.

Comment: Unlike a lot of questions that get posted here, this one seems to be philosophical: what is random once I reach into the bucket and pull out fruit, rather than how to do the calculation. Therefore, I’m not sure this answers the asked question.

Comment: Also, the question does not mention bananas.

Comment: Sorry. I meant oranges.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if you repeated the experiment many times.

Would you always get the same outcome?

Clearly there are several possible events you could observe -- $(\text{apple}, \text{apple})$, $(\text{apple}, \text{orange})$, $(\text{orange}, \text{apple})$ and $(\text{orange}, \text{orange})$, and which you get is not exactly predictable (though if we repeat this experiment many times, some possibilities may tend to occur more often than others).

Consequently we would typically tend to choose to model the outcome as a random event.

Note that the probability calculation is made as if we're standing before drawing the fruit, not after; once you have observed it – once you have a realization of your random variable, that observation is not a random quantity, it's data.